# (parent -> Child1 -> Child2). I am able to open child2 window using selenium. But not able to print anything after that. Execution freezes there

Tags: selenium

I have 3 windows (`parent` -> `Child1` -> `Child2`).I have written below code to open `Child2` window using selenium. But after the `Child2` window opens, control does not execute next line. 
Please note that I don't need to switch to `Child2` window. I am aware with switching window concept. I just need to print a simple message after the `Child2` window opens. But since it is not going to next line it is not printing the message. In Debug mode I saw that the control is not moving to next line after the `Child2` window opens.

```
 Set<String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> win = set.iterator();
    System.out.println(set);
    String parent = win.next();
    String child1 = win.next();

    //Switched to child1 window
    driver.switchTo().window(child1);

    // Performed some action on Child1
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtDescription")).sendKeys("test");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Code to open Child2
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("imgAddAssignTo")));



    // This line is not executing after the above line execution.
    System.out.println("closed");
```

Comment: You can add thread.sleep(10) before the last line. it may help sometimes. I know, it is not good practice to use sleep method but it helped sometimes for me.

Comment: Hi Murthi, I tried but it is not working. Since the control is not moving after second last line. It does not execute Thread.sleep(10000).